# Branch Deep Link with kotlin does not work on android device

Tags: kotlin, branch.io

I create an android App with kotlin, which I am integrating Branch IO for App sharing. I have implemented Share URL functionality with help of Branch with below code:

```
share.setOnClickListener {
        val lp = LinkProperties()
        val message = "Check out this product"
        val ss = ShareSheetStyle(this, "App", message)
            .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
            .setSharingTitle("Share With")

        val image = productData.mainImage
        val url = this.getString(R.string.image_URL) + image
        buo = Utility(this).prepareSharingLink(
            productData.id.toString(),
            "product",
            url,
            UtilityTools.getInstance().getValue(productData.name)
        )
        buo.showShareSheet(this, lp, ss, object : BranchLinkShareListener {
            override fun onShareLinkDialogLaunched() {}
            override fun onShareLinkDialogDismissed() {}
            override fun onLinkShareResponse(
                sharedLink: String,
                sharedChannel: String,
                error: BranchError?
            ) {
                val metaData: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                if (error == null) {
                    metaData[Defines.Jsonkey.SharedLink.key] = sharedLink
                } else {
                    metaData[Defines.Jsonkey.ShareError.key] = error.message
                }
            }

            override fun onChannelSelected(channelName: String) {}
        })

    }
```

prepareSharingLink is a function as follows :

```
 fun prepareSharingLink(
        itemID: String,
        itemType: String,
        imageURL: String?,
        customTitle: String = ""
    ): BranchUniversalObject {

        val canonical = itemType.plus("/").plus(itemID)
        var branchUniversalObject = BranchUniversalObject()
        branchUniversalObject.canonicalIdentifier = canonical
        branchUniversalObject.title = customTitle
        branchUniversalObject.setContentDescription("")
        branchUniversalObject.setContentImageUrl(imageURL!!)
        branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemType"] = itemType
        branchUniversalObject.contentMetadata.customMetadata["itemID"] = itemID
        branchUniversalObject.isLocallyIndexable
        branchUniversalObject.isPublicallyIndexable
        branchUniversalObject.setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PRIVATE)
        return branchUniversalObject
    }
```

When I click on share button in my UI, and I choose "copy to clipboard", then when I click on paste, there's no an URL copied.
I would like to know what should I change in my code to get the URL copied.

Comment: Hey, Lina, the SDK would automatically generate a short link on clicking on a channel using showShareSheet method. Could you share the Branch SDK response in this case?

Comment: In android studio emulater I got the URL as a response, but when I generate the apk and I install it in my device I got an empty result

Comment: I followed all instructions described here
 https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration

Comment: Can you see the Branch SDK response when you test on your real Device? You can enable logging like this - https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-testing#section-enable-logging

Comment: In android emulator I get the response but on my real device no response, I think there's some thing missing in cofigurations or some thing like this

Comment: Did you have any idea about using Android Troubleshooting ?

Comment: I'd suggest you reach out to us via https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket so that we may assist you further.